# localhost javascript bundled is trying to be injected to my website by an user. (Reported by Sentry an error and performance tracking tool)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, javascript-injection, client-side-attacks

I can see in Sentry report that,
Along with my *vendors~main-6319dfea084cb55e85bf.js,main-6319dfea084cb55e85bf.js* and other resource.scripts and resource.css files i can see **https://localhost:49506/7pp3ab609c5236b3bf34c2b621ac79ba.js** script is been injected and also- *GET https://localhost:49506/storage/userId* and *GET https://localhost:49506/storage/pendingRequests* api calls has been triggered.

The attacker tried this from EDGE browser.
The application was developed with typescript and Reactjs.

My questions are,

1. What type of attack it is?
2. How can i handled this?

Also if any additional info, please post here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That port troubled me too, the mqtt was not able to connect by website. 
So i just found the PID on windows by using "netstat -ano | findstr :49506"
and killed it by using "taskkill /PID <PID> /F"
All worked fine ....

Comment: It was something called sj-pulse-proxy-server-app in windows which caused the issues.

Answer (score 1):

Had a user complaining our website wouldn't work on their version of MacOS. The information already posted here is correct. Remove any application from your computer named Survey Junky and any browser extension you may have installed by a similar name such as SJ Pulse. I suspect the program puts a proxy on your computer and when the proxy isn't running your web browser stops working correctly. Or it just interferes with internet connections in general.